# Adding columns and puting value in a new row in R Script

Tags: r

I am trying to add particular columns of data frame and adding these values in a new row of the same data frame.

TCM<-colSums(df[3:16])--this add all the values
Now in the same file "TCM" I want to have new added values at the last row named Total.

Comment: What should happen to the first two columns of the new row ? If you want to set NA you could use `df[dim(df)[1]+1,3:16] = TCM`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need the last row to be of the same length with your other rows if you want to bind them. I can write the code assuming you want the first column to be "Total" and second column to be NA. If you have different values in mind simply modify the inputs for the respective values.

```
first_val = "Total"
second_val = NA
to_bind = c(first_val,second_val,TCM)
df = rbind(df,to_bind)
```